# Item can be accessed via Display Name and Item Name if useDisplayName is true?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa

I have an item named "/Registration" with a display name "/Register Here".

I was able to access the item via `https://url/registration/` and `https://url/register-here/`

Is this behavior expected if `useDisplayName` is set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This behavior is expected with `useDisplayName` value set to true.

`useDisplayName` adds extra logic to check whether Display Name of the item matches url segment (with extra processing for thinks like hyphens).

It does not remove the default logic. That's why accessing the page via `https://url/registration/` still works.